# Call `type` on a command that's self-aliased

Tags: command, alias

Sometimes a command is aliased to itself. For example:

```
$ type ls
ls is aliased to `ls -al'
```

How do I invoke `type` on the `ls` command itself (and not the alias)?

Comment: Would recommend `which` over `type` if this is for a program and not output purposes

Comment: @StanStrum Could you elaborate on what "output purposes" mean? Both commands output to `stdout` as I understand.

Comment: I mean while `type` gives more information, `which` tells you where the file is and does not need fancy regex to retrieve the path. (Would use `type` on the command line, would use `which` in a program)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the description of `type` in `man bash`:

> The  -P  option
>                 forces  a  PATH  search  for  each name, even if `type -t name` would not return file.  If a command is hashed, -p and -P print the hashed value,
>                 which is not necessarily the file that appears first in PATH

so

```
$ type ls
ls is aliased to `ls -FG'
$ type -P ls
/bin/ls
```

Also

```
$ type -a ls
ls is aliased to `ls -FG'
ls is /bin/ls
```

might be helpful sometimes.

Comment: Great - thank you! Although, I think one needs to be careful in using `-P`, or know what one is doing: 
`$ type cd` Result: `cd is aliased to 'cd'`
`$ type -P cd` Result: `/usr/bin/cd`. One might mistakenly think the `cd` command invokes `/usr/bin/cd`, when it in fact is built-in. In this case, the `-a` option is handy.

Comment: @flow2k Prefixing a command name with a backslash gives you access to the "real" command, foregoing any alias with that name. So if you had `ls` aliased to `ls -alh` and needed the "normal" behaviour, you'd use `\ls /path/to/dir` or whatever. =)